# Perform selector:withObject:afterDelay firing immediately, no delay

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, selector

I have a very strange error that I have never seen before. I have used this code hundreds of times before, but for some reason, the afterDelay is being completely disregarded.

My Code:

```
- (void)runIntro
{
if([self introDone])return;

UIImageView* back = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[AppDelegate shared] frame]];
[back setImage:[[AppDelegate shared] bgImage]];
[back setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

[self.view addSubview:back];

UIImageView* target = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([[AppDelegate shared] width]-250)/2.0, ([[AppDelegate shared] height]-350)/2.0, 250, 72)];
[target setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bpside.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:target];

Parabolic* wally = [[Parabolic alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([[AppDelegate shared] width]-200)/2.0, ([[AppDelegate shared] height]-314)/2.0+250, 200, 200)];
[wally setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wallyside1.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:wally];

[self performSelector:@selector(moveWallyIntro:) withObject:wally afterDelay:1];
[self performSelector:@selector(moveWallyIntro:) withObject:wally afterDelay:2];
}

- (void)moveWallyIntro:(Parabolic*)wally
{
    [wally runPBM:50 withDY:300 withDuration:0.5];
}
```

I know that all of the other code is working properly, but for whatever reason, the selectors are being performed **immediately**, which causes a major problem. This code is being run at the end of the `viewWillAppear` method. I have programmed this way many times before and this is the first time I've seen this happen.

UPDATE:

If I remove the code that adds the `back` UIImageView, this no longer is a problem. How can I add a **giant** image (3000x2000) in aspect fill format like this so it doesn't cause the program to hang? I'm using the same background image for iphone, ipad, etc., so it needs to be large for the retina iPads...

Comment: Wait, so what's your question now with the "update" comment? Are you still having delay problems, or now some other issue?

Comment: Well I can solve the delay issue by implementing the image a different way; I guess what I'm asking now is how can I efficiently implement my code that adds `back` as a scaled image so I can use one image for all 3 device types instead of making 3 versions of each background image.

Comment: Ok, still confused. Define "efficiently" if you would... Is your problem with sizing the UIImageVeiw to fill space, or an issue with load time on the image?

Comment: Unless you're screwing with the run loop, then I would say that these are executing properly, it's just that the original method is being executed in the wrong time and or place.